# JASidePanels how to change CenterPanel

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm using JASidePanels with storyboard. How should i change the centre view?
I'm unable to get self.sidePanelController.centerPanel as there's my self does not have that sidePanelController.

Did i miss out anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. i found my mistake. i forgot to import UIViewController+JASidePanel.h